# Galois Action and Specializations of Points

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I've been looking everywhere I can think of but I cannot find a definition of a Galois group acting on a variety that doesn't depend on coordinates but is also not phrased in massive generality. I want to show that a $K$-rational point is defined over a subfield $k$ if it is invariant under the Galois action but without the use of coordinates. Here's the specific question:

Let $K$ be a field and $A$ a finite $K$-algebra. Treating $A$ as an abstract variety, a homomorphism $\varphi: A\to K$ is a point of $A$ defined over $K$.

If $k$ is a subfield of $K$, what does it mean for the point corresponding to $\varphi$ to be defined over $k$, without referring to Galois action? Furthermore, how does one define the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/k)$ on the point corresponding to $\varphi$?

Comment: An element of the Galois group is an automorphism $\alpha: K \rightarrow K$. Composing $\varphi$ withh $\alpha$ gives another homomorphism $\alpha \circ \phi: A \rightarrow K$, and this defines the action of the Galois group on $K$-points. The point $\varphi$ is defined over $k$ if it factors through the inclusion $k \hookrightarrow K$.